# CKEditor - Issues with extraAllowedContent / ACF

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm loading some HTML content in a CKEditor instance which, among other elements, has a table.
Some cells of the table have the tag
`td contenteditable='true'` and others `contenteditable='false'`

When I load it in CKEditor this tag is removed by ACF.

I've added `extraContentAllowed` and it worked fine for the all other tags and elements but can't find the way to make it allow `contenteditable`.

```
echo "CKEDITOR.config.extraAllowedContent = 'p div td table tr td th(*)[*]{*}; table[contenteditable]';";
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are allowing all attributes `[*]`, there is no need to extra allow `contenteditable` attribute - `table[contenteditable]`. It is enough if you enter ACF configuration as shown below:

```
// Directly on HTML page
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraAllowedContent:'p div td table tr td th(*)[*]{*}'
});
```

or

```
// Inside config.js
config.extraAllowedContent = 'p div td table tr td th(*)[*]{*}';
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you swiderski, I tried as you suggested but it didn't work.It still strips the contenteditable tag.

Comment: This has to work. Have you cleared browser's cache? Where have you entered that configuration? Into `config.js` or directly on HTML page?